# Storing the pointer to a class in a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, wxwidgets

I have the following code as :-

```
wxSpinCtrl* m_spinner;
```

where `wxSpinCtrl` is a class and `m_spinner` is a pointer,what i require is something like we have:

```
int b;
int* a;
a = &b;
```

is the above kind of code available for

```
wxSpinCtrl* m_spinner;
```

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with, `wxSpinCtrl obj;` and then  `wxSpinCtrl* m_spinner = &obj;`, I fail to understand your question.

Comment: I think the question title should be "Storing the address of an object in a pointer".

Comment: The declaration of the class wxspinctrl is:-
"class WXDLLIMPEXP_CORE wxSpinCtrl : public wxSpinButton
"WXDLLIMPEXP is a macro here (DLL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course

```
wxSpinCtrl b;
wxSpinCtrl* a;
a = &b;
```

This will work only if wxSpinCtrl has a public default constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you want another reference to the same object use:

```
 wxSpinCtrl* m_spinner;
 wxSpinCtrl* other = m_spinner;
```

If you want a double pointer use:

```
 wxSpinCtrl* m_spinner;
 wxSpinCtrl** other = &m_spinner;
```

And as `Als` pointed out, this is also ok:

```
 wxSpinCtrl obj; 
 wxSpinCtrl* m_spinner = &obj;
```